# ASP.NET MVC C# list inside list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I'm using ASP.NET MVC to that enables user to takes exams, each exam contains a list of questions and each question contain multiple answer to form a multiple choice question. Here are my model

```
 public class Exam
{
    [Key]
    public string ExamID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    
    public bool Suffer { get; set; }
}
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public ICollection<String> Answer { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAns { get; set; }
}
```

It seems fine when I create exam with multiple questions, but when I want to get my list of answers from question, it returns null for my Answer list .Does C# allows to put a list inside a list or it comes from another issue?

This is my code for create and get exam i use in controller:
[HttpPost]

```
    public JsonResult Create(Exam exam,string ClassID)
    {
        if (exam.Time.ToString()!=null  ||exam.Deadline==null)
        {
            exam.Deadline = new DateTime(1990,1,1);
        }       
        Class @class = db.Classes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClassID == ClassID);          
        exam.Class = @class;
        exam.ExamID = ClassID +exam.Name;
        db.Exams.Add(exam);
        int a=db.SaveChanges();    
        return Json(a);
    } 
 public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Exam exam = db.Exams.Find(id);
 
        if (exam == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        foreach(Question question in exam.Questions)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(question.Answer.Count);
        }
```

I use Debug.WriteLine to check whether there is any answer string in question and it returns null in this step

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to access the lists?

Comment: Yes, you can have a list of lists. Can you show your code that creates the Exams and then tries to pull out the list of answers?

Comment: i have edited and added my code in my post

Comment: It looks you're only accessing the object itself and not the relations try with a .Include()

```.Include(blog => blog.Posts)```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: tried to replace the finding object code with     Exam exam = db.Exams.Include(x => x.Questions).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExamID == id); but it gives the same issue

Comment: I'd double check the data source to confirm that there are actually answers associated with the questions? And then double check that you're connecting to the correct data source.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use Eager loading. So you have to use Include method.
In order have multiple levels of depth you have to use ThenInclude after Include method.

```
db.Exams.Include(x => x.Questions).ThenInclude(y => y.Answers).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExamID == id);
```

Official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: been searching for an hour but can't find ThenInclude(), how can i use that method?

Comment: It is in same class as the Include.  EntityFrameworkCore =>
 EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions

Comment: still not fix the issue even using Then Include...

Comment: In your Model. You have ICollection<String> Answer.  You have to create class Answer and make ICollection<Answer> Answers. Answer will have properties Id and Title and foreign key Question_id.